Horizontal scrollable grid in css with upto 2 rows
I am designing a simple horizontal scrollable grid. Requirement is to have at max 2 rows. If the cells fit in one row, it should show one row else show wrap remaining items in next row. Is this possible with grid or do I have to go with flex.
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 162px);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 162px);
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-auto-columns: 162px;
  gap: 8px;
  overflow-x: auto;
  padding: 8px;
}

.grid-item {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

Problem: Grid in red looks fine because it has more no of cells, so it wraps to second row, but grid in yellow has less items but still wraps in second row.


It is because of grid-auto-flow: column;, remove it and see it that what you want?

What do you mean by "if the cells fit into one row" if you want the whole thing to scroll horizontally? Surely if you're allowing horizontal scrolling, you could fit any number of cells into one row? Are you planning to set a fixed limit to the scroll width, or a limit on the number of cells in any row? Also, your question title says "up to n rows", but in the text of your question you say there's a "maximum of 2 rows". Please edit your question to better describe the use case, and clarify exactly what the requirements are.

By removing (grid-auto-flow: column;) it will work. Or you can use grid-auto-flow: row;
[https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-auto-flow]


Example : [https://jsfiddle.net/n8rjhs56/1/]

